# Linux server with windows users editing permissions

Tags: linux

So I am not very familiar with servers in general so please bear with me.

There are two users (A + B), Both users have a windows account on a private PC with a connection to the linux box over the network. Any file made on either windows PC is saved as linux user account 'C'. Both users have a user account on the linux box (A + B). All user accounts ( A, B and C) have the group called 'group'.

This is a look at a test directory I made in windows.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 A      group 34 Oct 26 10:54 testmadeonlinuxUserA.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 B      group 34 Oct 26 10:54 testmadeonlinuxUserB.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 C      group 6 Oct 26 10:54  testmadeonwindows.txt
```

The problem:
The windows account (C) has access to modify files made by both linux accounts A and B and can create files in directories made by both linux accounts A and B.

However neither linux account can access any file made through windows nor can they create files in a windows created directory.

This is a problem... How can we fix this so that linux user A and B can modify and create files in directories made by C and vice versa. Crucially this needs to apply for all future files, I'm not looking for a temporary fix which will work for one directory as that's what we are doing currently.

Any Help Appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Kyle.

Comment: What is the umask setting of your C user?

Comment: 022 is the umask

Answer (score 0):

Then set the umask to 002 for the user C. Put following line to your C user .bashrc (if it uses bash).

```
umask 002
```

All new directories should have rwx group access rights. You'll have to modify existing ones...